# Adding column to many-to-many table using Liferay

Tags: database, liferay, liferay-service-builder

I would like to add a column to the association table using service builder on liferay!

```
<entity name="entity1" local-service="true" remote-service="false">

    <column name="entity1Id" type="long" primary="true" id-type="sequence"

        id-param="id_entity1_sequence"></column>

    <column name="name" type="String"></column>

    <column name="entity2s" type="Collection" mapping-table="entity1_entity2"
        entity="entity2"></column>

        <finder name="Name" return-type="entity1" unique="true">
        <finder-column name="name"></finder-column>

    </finder>

</entity>

<entity name="entity2" local-service="true" remote-service="false">

    <column name="entity2Id" type="long" primary="true" id-type="sequence"

        id-param="id_entity2_sequence"></column>

    <column name="header" type="String"></column>

    <column name="value" type="String"></column>

    <column name="entity1s" type="Collection" mapping-table="entity1_entity2"
        entity="entity1"></column>


</entity>
```

I mean I need to add a column to entity1_entity2 table

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think you would take a look this tutorial (it's splitted in 3 parts):

- Part I:
  http://www.liferaysavvy.com/2014/01/liferay-service-builder-many-to-many.html
- Part II:
  http://www.liferaysavvy.com/2014/01/liferay-service-builder-many-to-many_12.html
- Part III:
  http://www.liferaysavvy.com/2014/01/liferay-service-builder-many-to-many_3547.html

Regards.

Comment: It's not realy what I was looking for, It's nearly similar but in my case I'm looking to add a column to the mapping-table course_student!!
can get my point?

Comment: In the first part, the tutorial says that 3 tables are created:
 | Table meera_Students: registries for students
 | Table meera_Courses: registries for courses
 | Table meera_Students_Courses: registries for relations course-student |

 Isn't it the target that you are looking for?

Comment: first I would like to think you Mr Carlos for your help but what I'm looking for is to add an attribute (or column) to the meera_Students_Courses table!!! which means I the meera_Students_Courses table should contain :
(Pk(course_PK,student_PK),anotherColumn)